# QGIS Essen 2.14.0 OpenLayers plugins running Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: openlayers-2

I cannot make any OpenLayers plugin visible for the part of the world for which I plot vector points. I set CRS to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. After adding a layer of points it should be trivial to click on one of the opened layers and have a map, but the map does not show.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved: I figured out that it is a matter of CRS. I must not take pseudo mercator (as advertised by some), but mercator then I can display an open map along with my points.